# How to replace textbox column to checkbox column in datagridview with mysql query

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have this problem where I want to convert textbox column to checkbox in vb.net. The data is from mysql and I want one column to be displayed as checkbox column.

Here is my code so far:

```
Private Sub data_load()

     Dim mycommand As New MySqlCommand
     Dim myadapter As New MySqlDataAdapter
     Dim mydata As New DataTable

     conn = New MySqlConnection
     conn.ConnectionString = connstr

     conn.Open()

     mycommand.Connection = conn
     mycommand.CommandText = "SELECT locator_id, name AS 'NAME', date AS 'DATE', destination AS 'DESTINATION', time_leave AS 'TIME LEAVE', time_return AS 'TIME RETURN', isOfficial AS 'OFFICIAL?' FROM locator_table ORDER BY locator_id DESC"

     myadapter.SelectCommand = mycommand
     myadapter.Fill(mydata)

     DataGridView1.DataSource = mydata
     DataGridView1.Refresh()
End Sub
```

This is the image:

[image: result]

As you can see `Official?` column is not checkbox.

Now, I want `Official?` to be checkbox column. The value in `Official?` column is only 1 and 0. When the value is 1 checkbox should be check otherwise uncheck. How to achieve this?

Comment: The grid will automatically create a check box column if the bound data is type `Boolean`.  If you're unable to modify your data such that you're binding `Boolean` values, you will need to add at least that column for yourself.  You can add a column in the designer and set the `DataPropertyName` to configure binding.  If you're creating one of the columns manually, I'd probably create them all.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the columns to the DataTable manually specifying the Boolean datatype for the OFFICIAL? column. When the DataTable is bound to the grid it will display check boxes.

You can pass your connection string directly to the constructor of the connection and pass the command text and connection directly to the constructor of the command. The Using...End Using blocks ensure that the database objects are closed and disposed even if there is an error.

If you need a DataAdapter later to Update the database you can create one then.

```
Private Sub data_load()
    Dim mydata As New DataTable
    mydata.Columns.Add("locator_id", GetType(Integer))
    mydata.Columns.Add("NAME", GetType(String))
    mydata.Columns.Add("DATE", GetType(Date))
    mydata.Columns.Add("DESTINATION", GetType(String))
    mydata.Columns.Add("TIME LEAVE", GetType(String))
    mydata.Columns.Add("TIME RETURN", GetType(String))
    mydata.Columns.Add("OFFICIAL?", GetType(Boolean))
    Using conn As New MySqlConnection(constr)
        Using mycommand As New MySqlCommand("SELECT locator_id, name AS 'NAME', date AS 'DATE', destination AS 'DESTINATION', time_leave AS 'TIME LEAVE', time_return AS 'TIME RETURN', isOfficial AS 'OFFICIAL?' FROM locator_table ORDER BY locator_id DESC", conn)
            conn.Open()
            mydata.Load(mycommand.ExecuteReader)
        End Using
    End Using
    DataGridView1.DataSource = mydata
End Sub
```